# Issue with the output of pure functions

Tags: function-construction, programming, symbolic

I am getting the operator **&** in outputs of pure functions. e.g. with the following code

```
transl[t0_] := Function[{f, t}, f[t + t0]];

dt = Function[{f}, f']; 

PnUnMinusPnM1UnM1 := 
 Function[{op, t0, t, a, n, p1, p2, pn, u1, u2, un}, op[1] + a transl[t0][op[p1], t] + a^2 (transl[t0][op[p2], t])];

PnUnMinusPnM1UnM1[dt, t0, t, a, n, p1, p2, pn, u1, u2, un]
```

I am getting the output

$(0\&)+a^2\ \text{p2}'(t+\text{t0})+a\ \text{p1}'(t+\text{t0})$

Does anyone know what is going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your syntax is jumbled and it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to simplifies some heavy formula and I have just cut part of a line of the code. It is some recurrent formula which require some amount of math to be explained.

Comment: try evaluating 1' remembering that dt[f] is just f' and the first term of the body of your function PnUnMinusPmM1UnM1 (not a good name for a function in a SX question by the way!) is op[1] == dt[1] == 1'

Comment: I've put some guidance in the comments section but there are things you can do to help yourself here such as simplifying the function to a minimum size to demonstrate the problem.  Trace back the execution of your function to see what is happening (Trace is useful here).  Perhaps you realise that 0& is a constant function that always returns 0?  I doubt you want to add that to other terms as + is not defined out of the box for functions.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of 1 is 0&. That is, Derivative interprets the argument "1" to be a constant function, and the derivative of a constant function is a constant function that is everywhere 0. That is exactly what 0& is.

Comment: Okay, but how could one simplify formula of the form $16 \left((0\&)^2+1\right)^2 \sin ^4\left(\frac{\pi }{m}\right)$?

Comment: The question rather is, why are you differentiating a constant function in this way: `Function[f, f'][1]`?

Comment: 0& needs an argument to be evaluated.